# Regular expression seems not to work in Where-Object cmdlet

Tags: regex, powershell, pipe

I am trying to add quote characters around two fields in a file of comma separated lines.  Here is one line of data:

```
1/22/2018 0:00:00,0000000,001B9706BE,1,21,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

which I would like to become this:

```
1/22/2018 0:00:00,"0000000","001B9706BE",1,21,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I began developing my regular expression in a simple PowerShell script, and soon I have the following:

```
$strData = '1/29/2018 0:00:00,0000000,001B9706BE,1,21,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'
$strNew = $strData -replace "([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)",'$1,"$2","$3",$4'
$strNew
```

which gives me this output:

```
1/29/2018 0:00:00,"0000000","001B9706BE",1,21,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Great! I'm all set.  Extend this example to the general case of a file of similar lines of data:

```
Get-Content test_data.csv | Where-Object -FilterScript {
    $_ -replace "([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)", '$1,"$2","$3",$4'
}
```

This is a listing of test_data.csv:

```
1/29/2018 0:00:00,0000000,001B9706BE,1,21,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1/29/2018 0:00:00,104938428,0016C4C483,1,45,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,35,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1/29/2018 0:00:00,104943875,0016C4B0BC,1,31,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1/29/2018 0:00:00,104948067,0016C4834D,1,33,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

This is the output of my script:

```
1/29/2018 0:00:00,0000000,001B9706BE,1,21,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1/29/2018 0:00:00,104938428,0016C4C483,1,45,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,35,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1/29/2018 0:00:00,104943875,0016C4B0BC,1,31,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1/29/2018 0:00:00,104948067,0016C4834D,1,33,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I have also tried this version of the script:

```
Get-Content test_data.csv | Where-Object -FilterScript {
    $_ -replace "([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)", "`$1,`"`$2`",`"`$3`",$4"
}
```

and obtained the same results.

My simple test script has convinced me that the regex is correct, but something happens when I use that regex inside a filter script in the `Where-Object` cmdlet.

What simple, yet critical, detail am I overlooking here?

Here is my PSVerion:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10586  117
```

Comment: version 5.1.16299.98 here...all 3 produce the same result

Comment: there are obviously workarounds...i tried as csv and it worked...whats your end of line character out of curiousity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how `Where-Object` works. The cmdlet outputs those input lines for which the `-FilterScript` expression evaluates to `$true`. It does NOT output whatever you do inside that scriptblock (you'd use `ForEach-Object` for that).

You don't need either `Where-Object` or `ForEach-Object`, though. Just put `Get-Content` in parentheses and use that as the first operand for the `-replace` operator. You also don't need the 4th capturing group. I would recommend anchoring the expression at the beginning of the string, though.

```
(Get-Content test_data.csv) -replace '^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)', '$1,"$2","$3"'
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work here. I used `ForEach-Object` to process each record.

```
Get-Content test_data.csv |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)", '$1,"$2","$3",$4' }
```

This also seems to work. Uses the ? to create a reluctant (lazy) capture.

```
Get-Content test_data.csv |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*)', '$1,"$2","$3",$4' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just make a small change to what you have in order for this to work.  Simply change the script to the following, noting that I changed the `-FilterScript` to a `ForEach-Object` and fixed a minor typo that you had on the last item in the regular expression with the quotes:

```
Get-Content c:\temp\test_data.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace "([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)", "`$1,`"`$2`",`"`$3`",`"`$4"
}
```

I tested this with the data you provided and it adds the quotes to the correct columns.

Comment: This solution added one extra quote:

1/29/2018 0:00:00,"0000000","001B9706BE","1,21,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

The second part of the replace expression should be:

"`$1,`"`$2`",`"`$3`",`$4"

And then it woks correctly.  I still prefer answer 1 for its conciseness.